# Read ITSO smart card information using NFC connection in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an application where i have to read information from ITSO smart card. And it supports below three technologies for filter ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.
`android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA
android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable`
Now when I using below code

```
byte[] apduCmd = {
                0x00, //CLA
                (byte)0xA4, //INS select
                0x00, //P1
                0x00, //P2
                0x02 //LE
        };
     Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);                
                    try {
                        isoDep.connect();                    
                       byte[] result = isoDep.transceive(apduCmd);
                        Log.i(TAG, "SELECT: " + bytesToHex(result));
                        if (!(result[0] == (byte) 0x90 && result[1] == (byte) 0x00)) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{                        
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Read successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Above code gives me success bytes i.e. 9000
Now I am not sure what to do next? How to read complete Data/information from this ITSO card. (this card is type of bus ticket).
Any suggestion?

Thanks Michael, i have read the document [ITSO specification](https://www.itso.org.uk/the-specification/specification-resources/publicly-available-specification/), and got idea to create command to read the data from the card.
I execute the commands in below sequence.

```
1) SELECT DIRECTORY- 906A000000
2) SELECT APPLICATION- 905A0000031602A000
3) READ DATA- 90BD0000070400000000000000 (File number- 4)
4) ADDITIONAL FRAME- 90AF000000 (This will execute only if we have Additional frame in response.)
```

And i am getting response like below for each file ( below response if for file number 4)

```
Response: 230A00009469FA0798004600002698400100000000000000000000000000000000042C00C0001CDC131089EB4A583BC000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Now I am not sure how get the information from this?
**Can i get all information at once in XML or JSON?** Is there any easier way to do this?

**Update 10/05/2016**
I got the shell information in HEX String, Can you help me to decode the textual information from it. (Reference ITSO specification given above.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by reading and (partially) implementing the [ITSO specifications](https://www.itso.org.uk/the-specification/specification-resources/publicly-available-specification/). I guess specifically part 10 (Customer Media Definitions) would be of interest for you since it defines the APDU commands and file structures of cards.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it helped me and the cards I have is DESFire (CMD 7), so the relevant section there is section 8 of the document. Now I am getting byte array for READ DATA command. Now how can i get relevant information from it?

Comment: Please see my update question.

Comment: The link to the specs is broken and should be https://www.itso.org.uk/services/itso-specification/  I don't have enough rep here to edit without being put in the queue, and that's apparently full